# React Native update for android Phone

Tags: react-native, kotlin, expo

I have created a simple application using React Native and generated an APK file for Android phones by using Expo eject , ./gradlew clean , npx react-native-run . After that, I used CodePush in App Center, which is owned by Microsoft, to update the APK file. I  want to achieve the same update functionality using GitHub Actions.

To clarify, I  would like to automatically update the application on users' Android phones when you push changes to your GitHub repository, without publishing the app on the Play Store

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up a GitHub Actions workflow that triggers a CodePush release when you push changes to your repository.

You will need to generate `APPCENTER_ACCESS_TOKEN` is used to authenticate with the App Center CLI. Here's how you can generate an App Center Access Token:

- Log into the App Center portal.
- Click on the profile icon on the upper right of the screen.
- Select "User settings" from the drop-down menu.
- Scroll down to the "API Tokens" section.
- Click on the "New API Token" button.
- Provide a description for your token (this can be anything you like,
  it's just a note for you).
- Select the access level for the token. If you're using it for
  CodePush, "Full Access" is required.
- Click the "Add new API token" button. The new token will be
  displayed.
- Copy the token immediately and store it safely - you won't be able to
  see it again once you navigate away from the page.

Generate your codepush deployment key:

- Get your CodePush Deployment Key: You can find this key in the App
  Center under your app's Distribute > CodePush section. Select the app
  and deployment (Staging or Production) for which you want the key.

After this, you'll have to configure your Github actions:

- Configure GitHub Secrets: To push updates to App Center, you need to
  have the App Center access token. You can store this access token in
  your repository secrets. To do this, go to your GitHub repository >
  Settings > Secrets, and add a new secret with the name
  `APPCENTER_ACCESS_TOKEN` and the value as your actual App Center access
  token.
- Add the Deployment Key to GitHub Secrets: Go to your GitHub
  repository > Settings > Secrets, and add a new secret. You can name
  it something like CODEPUSH_DEPLOYMENT_KEY, and paste your actual
  deployment key as the value.
- Create a GitHub Actions workflow file: This file, typically named
  `main.yml`, goes in the `.github/workflows` directory of your repository.
  The workflow will trigger whenever you push changes to the
  repository.

This is how your .yml file might look like :

```
name: Deploy with CodePush

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 14

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci

      - name: Deploy to CodePush
        run: npx appcenter codepush release-react -a <OwnerName>/<AppName> -d <DeploymentName> -k ${{ secrets.CODEPUSH_DEPLOYMENT_KEY }}
        env:
          APPCENTER_ACCESS_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.APPCENTER_ACCESS_TOKEN }}
```

Replace `<OwnerName>`, `<AppName>`, and `<DeploymentName>` with your actual App Center account details.

Now, whenever you push changes to the main branch of your GitHub repository, the GitHub Actions workflow will automatically trigger, deploying updates to your app via CodePush.

You can target any branch/branches you want in :

```
branches: [ main ]
```

:)

Comment: "Is it possible to update an APK file that is installed on an Android phone without using a third-party service provider or sharing the source code with a third-party server? I want the APK file on the Android phone to be updated when I change the code  !! Does this way works

Comment: CodePush and other over the air update providers work with JS bundle of your app. So you javascript bundle of the react native app is being uploaded to cloud and will be downloaded once the user opens the app. This means, if you have javascript changes only, UI components, business logic and etc. this approach will work. But if you have any native changes, any packages installed that use native modules in android/ios folder, this won't work.

Comment: If there're changes in the native side of the app, the only way you can distribute these is to reinstall the build, doesn't matter of it's IOS .ipa or Android .apk. I'd advice you to take a look at this article: https://www.techtarget.com/searchmobilecomputing/definition/OTA-update-over-the-air-update#:~:text=An%20over-the-air%20(,Wi-Fi%20or%20mobile%20broadband.